# What is the difference between velocity of wave and velocity of pulse on a string wave?

Tags: waves, acoustics, velocity

I have read in my textbook that velocity of a wave remains constant but then there was a question to find velocity of **pulse** as a function of x in a vertically hanged rope.(where **x** is the position of particle  as we move up a rope )  now that came out ***v=√xg*** But that means velocity of pulse *changes* as we move up ? I am confused

Comment: When you say velocity of wave is constant, what type of wave are you talking about?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If your textbook really says that wave velocities are constant in all circumstances, you need to study a better textbook. Lens design, for example, involves choosing materials and crafting shapes that use changes in wave velocity to direct waves to a focal point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a non-dispersive system the velocity of a wave and a pulse are the same. In the particular case of a string the velocity is given by:

$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{T}{\rho}} $$

where $T$ is the tension in the string and $\rho$ is the linear density (mess per unit length). Both a continuous wave and an isolated pulse will travel along the string at this speed.

The reason that the velocity (of both a wave and a pulse) changes in your problem is because the tension in the rope changes. The topmost part of the rope has to support the whole mass of the rope so the tension is $mg$ where $m$ is the mass of the rope, while the bottom most part of the rope isn't supporting anything so the tension is zero. Since the tension increases as we move up the rope the wave and pulse velocity increase as well.